# Permanently display color palette during slideshow - MS PowerPoint

Tags: powerpoint

I am making video lessons using MS PowerPoint.

Unfortunately, my productivity is greatly reduced by the fact that during a slideshow, it takes:

- 4 clicks to change from a red pen to a blue highlighter
- Then, changing to a green pen takes a further 4 clicks.

This is becoming a nuisance as these 3 second bursts of inactivity have to be tediously video edited to make lessons engaging.

Keyboard shortcuts (`Ctrl-I` and `Ctrl-P`) are only useful if I use only one colour each for the pen and highlighter, and merely switch between the two.

I wanted to know if anything exists to permanently display a colour palette at the bottom of each slide.
I know this is possible, because I have used [OfficeOne InkTools](http://officeone.mvps.org/inktools/inktools.html) which works fine on PowerPoint 2013, but it does not have all the features I would like.
I have experience coding, and am willing to make this feature myself if I was walked through which Objects I needed to modify etc.

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If you wanted to have some kind of dynamically visible/hidden interactive toolbar during your slideshow like the one above, you could add a form to your project with as many buttons as you require colours and call a Sub to open that form when you click on an object on the slide (visible or not). To do this, add a shape to your slide (or master) and set it's mouse click action to run this macro in a standard module:

```
Sub ChangePenColour()
  frmChangePenColour.Show
End Sub
```

Then create a form called frmChangePenColour and add 7 buttons to it called btn1 to btn6 and btnCancel.

Then add this code to the form:

```
' =======================================================
' Pen Colour Demo by YOUpresent
' Visit http://youpresent.co.uk for more PowerPoint stuff
' =======================================================
Option Explicit

Private Sub btn1_Click()
  ChangePointerColor btn1.BackColor
  Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub btn2_Click()
  ChangePointerColor btn2.BackColor
  Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub btn3_Click()
  ChangePointerColor btn3.BackColor
  Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub btn4_Click()
  ChangePointerColor btn4.BackColor
  Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub btn5_Click()
  ChangePointerColor btn5.BackColor
  Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub btn6_Click()
  ChangePointerColor btn6.BackColor
  Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
  CentreForm Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  With SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.Design.SlideMaster.Theme
    btn1.BackColor = .ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent1).RGB
    btn2.BackColor = .ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent2).RGB
    btn3.BackColor = .ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent3).RGB
    btn4.BackColor = .ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent4).RGB
    btn5.BackColor = .ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent5).RGB
    btn6.BackColor = .ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent6).RGB
  End With
End Sub

Sub ChangePointerColor(lRGB As Long)
  With SlideShowWindows(1).View
    .PointerColor = lRGB
    .PointerType = ppSlideShowPointerPen
  End With
End Sub

Private Sub btnCancel_Click()
  Unload Me
End Sub

' Centres a form wrt the PowerPoint application window
Public Sub CentreForm(thisForm As Object)
  On Error Resume Next
  ' Position in the centre of the PowerPoint window
  With thisForm
    .Left = Application.Left + ((Application.Width / 2) - (.Width / 2))
    .Top = Application.Top + ((Application.Height / 2) - (.Height / 2))
  End With
  If Err Then Debug.Print Err & Err.Description & " in CentreForm"
  On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Now when you run the slide show, you can click on your chosen active shape to open the colour picker and start annotating in that colour.

Then if you want that toolbar to appear automatically when the slide show starts and not disappear when a colour is clicked, you could addd this sub:

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
  frmChangePenColour.Show
End Sub
```

And change the form's ShowModal property to false.

You'll probably want to tweak the UI logic but this should be enough to get you going.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts:

You can add a couple of VBA routines to your file, something like these (adjust the RGB values as you wish):

```
Sub Blue()
    With SlideShowWindows(1).View.PointerColor
        .RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    End With
End Sub

Sub Red()
    With SlideShowWindows(1).View.PointerColor
        .RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End With
End Sub
```

Add more as needed for other colors.

Then draw a couple rectangles or other shape on the slide (or master) and assign each rectangle an action setting of RUN MACRO:  Blue  (or red or whatever).

You can make these transparent so it's not obvious to anyone viewing the presentation that there any shapes there.

Press Ctrl+A to change the pointer to an arrow (so you can click on things), click the shape for the color you want, then press Ctrl+P to turn the cursor back to a pen so you can draw ... in the selected color.

==================

Another totally different approach would be to add the annotations in advance on two different slides and transition between them or on one slide and animate them on as needed.